# How to copy/paste text from remote system?

Tags: vnc, remote-access, clipboard

I used to access a remote system via VNC viewer, but when I copy some text from the remote system and paste it in my text editor(local system), nothing happens. Do I need to install any additional packages to achieve this task?

**Updates:**
There is no such option found in the Real VNC properties.

[image: Screenshot]

I just get the following output:

```
karthick@karthick:~$ vncconfig         
No VNC extension on display :0.0
```

**Updated:**

```
karthick@karthick:~$ vncserver

Warning: karthick:1 is taken because of /tmp/.X1-lock
Remove this file if there is no X server karthick:1

Warning: karthick:2 is taken because of /tmp/.X2-lock
Remove this file if there is no X server karthick:2

New 'X' desktop is karthick:4

Starting applications specified in /home/karthick/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/karthick/.vnc/karthick:4.log

karthick@karthick:~$ vncconfig -display :1 
vncconfig: unable to open display ":1"
```

[image]

Comment: This is turning into a bit of a mess. Can you state somewhere what the setup is. What OS is the client? What OS is the server? What client and server software are you using on each?

Comment: Client runs windows XP and the server runs ubuntu 10.10. And the client runs `Real VNC` and the server runs `vncviewer`. Do you need anyother information ?

Comment: `vncviewer` is not a VNC server (the clue's in the name :P)

Comment: I have already installed `vnc4server` too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There will be a ***.vnc*** directory in your home folder. In this directory there will be few files named like **<computer name>:<number>.extension**
For example my laptop contains following two files in .vnc directory.

```
adnan-laptop:1.log
adnan-laptop:1.pid
```

The **:1** in the above file names shows that the vnc server is running on display ***:1***.

Now connect to your VNC server and from the connected session run vncconfig as follows:

```
vncconfig -display :1
```

This will show a small window with clipboard related options. Check all the options and dont close the window. Now you should be able to copy paste from/to remote system.

Comment: karthick@karthick:~$ vncconfig -display :1  
vncconfig: unable to open display ":1"

Comment: @karthick87: what command are you using to run vnc server? have you checked .vnc directory in your home folder? does it contain files like karthick:1.pid?

Comment: Pls see the updates in my question..

Comment: @karthick87: the output of vncserver says that "New 'X' desktop is karthick:4" so you should run "vncconfig -display:4"

Comment: Now i am getting the following output,        karthick@karthick:~$ vncconfig -display :5
No VNC extension on display :5

Comment: @binW For me inside the .vnc directory there are multiple entries with display `1`. For example `slc01ags:1.log` and `slc04lyo:1.log`. So how do I specify which display `1`while running the command `vncconfig -display :1`?

Comment: The command ```vncconfig -display :1``` works for me but why can't we close the window?  Is there a way to set this once and for all?

Comment: For people reading this answer **DON'T CLOSE THE WINDOW** is the keyword. I missed that the first time and was unable to achieve the desired result.

Comment: I get `No VNC extension on display :1`

Answer (score 20):

1. Install:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install autocutsel
   ```
2. Run `vi /home/b37399/.vnc/xstartup` and add this line:

   ```
   autocutsel -fork
   ```

   like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   xrdb $HOME/.Xresources  
   autocutsel -fork  
   startxfce4 &
   ```
3. Restart `vncserver`

Comment: autocutsel worked for me, but not the "vncconfig -nowin &" or "vncconfig -display :1"

Comment: not working on debian 8.10

Comment: this works for me on Debian 9

Comment: As `vncconfig` appears to only be available with TigerVNC setups, the `autocutsel` trick helped - thanks!

Comment: The fix applies to both copying to and from the remote system. Tested on Mac OS High Sierra / Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 10):

I use the following line in my login-script:

```
vncconfig -nowin&
```

Hope it works for you!?

Comment: Do you run this before `vnc4server` or after?

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the VNC client that you are using. If you are using RealVNC then open the VNC Viewer **Properties** dialog and, on the **Inputs tab**, turn on **Share clipboard with VNC Server**.

**UPDATE:**
Try this. Connect using **vncviewer** and run **vncconfig** within the remote window, check the options regarding the clipboard and then try.
[image]

Comment: Pls see my updates in the question.

Comment: @karthick87: you are looking at VNC server's properties. Go to VNC viewer's Properties dialog

Comment: No its not there in VNC viewer properties.Look @ the snapshot pls.

Comment: @karthick87: I have updated the answer. Plz try the vncconfig method. I believe it will work because it has always worked for me.

Comment: Do you want me to type vncconfig in command prompt ?

Comment: @karthick87: run 'vncconfig' from command prompt or using Alt+F2. It will open a VNC Config dialog as shown in the image above. Check all the options and then try copy-pasting between local and remote systems.

Comment: @karthick87: did it help?

Comment: I will try that tonight and let me update the status :)

Comment: Pls see the output on my question..

Comment: @karthick87: can you plz tell us what command line are you using to run vnc server. Also plz run "ps ax|grep Xvnc" and add its output to the question. And plz remember to add @binW in the comment when you reply to me because otherwise I dont get notified.

Comment: I get 'No VNC extension on display :1'

Answer (score 3):

I use Remote login with vnc-ltsp-config with GNOME Desktop Environment on CentOS 5.9. From experimenting today, I managed to get cut and paste working for the session and the login prompt (because I'm lazy and would rather cut and paste difficult passwords).

1. Created a file **vncconfig.desktop** in the **/etc/xdg/autostart** directory which enabled cut and paste during the session after login. The vncconfig process is run as the logged in user.

   > [Desktop Entry]
   >   Name=No name
   >   Encoding=UTF-8
   >   Version=1.0
   >   Exec=vncconfig -nowin
   >   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
2. Added `vncconfig -nowin &` to the bottom of the file **/etc/gdm/Init/Desktop** which enabled cut and paste in the session during login but terminates after login. The vncconfig process is run as root.
3. Adding `vncconfig -nowin &` to the bottom of the file **/etc/gdm/PostLogin/Desktop** also enabled cut and paste during the session after login. The vncconfig process is run as root however.

Comment: This seems to be the only solution where copy-and-paste is enabled at startup/boot/login and in the background.  I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 and could not get @Clausi's answer to work.

Comment: At the end of the day, I ditched VNC for NoMachine NX.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above suggestions with no luck.

I eventually solved it by replacing the vnc server from `tightvncserver` to `vnc4server`

On any manner, make sure that under `~/.vnc/xstartup` you have the line

```
vncconfig -iconic &
```

Comment: This is the **only** suggestion that worked for me, thanks! I was also using `tightvncserver`, and I had `autocutsel -fork` in my `xstartup`. But the clipboard was only working from remove to local machine (not the other way around). I installed `vnc4server` and added `vncconfig -iconic &` right after `autocutsel -fork`. Clipboard is now working bidirectionally!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [www.letscopypaste.com](http://www.letscopypaste.com) or [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) .
They offer simple to use clipboard capability.

Answer (score 1):

Using tightvnc (with the command: vncviewer) on Puppy Linux, I have to **press F8** in the remote window to bring up the VNC menu.  The VNC menu has entries for "Clipboard: local -> remote" and "Clipboard: local <- remote".  I have to copy some text, use either of those entries, and then paste on the other system.  I don't know if this is related to your particular problem, but it does behave like the symptoms you described if I don't use the menu.

Comment: Thank you. `vncconfig` did nothing this time, but I remember that adding it at the xstartup you can enable that feature. But using F8 I can enable or disable easily the direcction of the data, enabling only Remote->Local and never the opossite.

Comment: in my linux setup, I menu pop up but either copying didnt worked :( thanks for this menu hint, I wonder how did you find, there in the help menu they didnt show

Answer (score 1):

In a new terminal window, I used the command `vncconfig`, the command keeps running and you can use the copy and paste functions in other windows or terminals.

Answer (score 0):

The VNC viewer you are using has to support this feature otherwise you're just copying it localy on the remote system.

Answer (score 0):

Some commentary on your problem:
RealVNC's is proprietary and it's clipboard support may be entirely incompatible with tightvncserver. I've used both, together, in the past but I don't remember 100% if clipboard sharing worked bettween them. 
I do know for sure that RealVNC-server paired with RealVNC-viewer did accommodate clipboard sharing; but RealVNC-server is not free (as in $$s)

You might try:

- tightvnc viewer from http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php It *might* be more compatible with whatever method tightvncserver used to share the clipboard.
- or, perhaps you could go with an alternate protocol, ie NX (nxserver/nxclient ... some info at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NomachineNX). Clipboard sharing worked for me on that without any custom settings.

Answer (score 0):

One more cause for this is multiple instances of vncconfig instances running conflicting with each other. In my case i had custom vncserver setup, but the vncconfig started as part of the system boot conflicted with the custom vncconfig setting.

To resolve this kill unwanted vncconfig instances running.

To get the list of vncconfig instances currently running:

`ps -ef | grep vncconfig`

To kill :

`kill -9 <process_id>`

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code hereThis below config works perfectly fine for Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Please freshly copy-paste/replace the below config to ~/.vnc/xstartup and restart your vnc.  It will definitely work.  
_____________________________________

#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
autocutsel -fork  
vncconfig -iconic &
vncconfig -nowin &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &

gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could fix this is to install clipIt.

Without ClipIt, I could only paste from VNC client to Console.

ClipIt took care of copying clipboard information to the GDE3 clipboard, so that I could do an insert in Terminal for example.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I have tried all the solutions above but none worked. The real solution for me is to kill the process `klipper`. Not sure why but this process is the root cause of preventing me from copy and paste from windows to VNC.

```
ps aux|grep klipper
kill -9 <klipper_pid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Different vncservers locate their configurations in different directories. In case you can't change your configuration despite adding `autocutsel -fork` in `~/.vnc/xstartup`, you could also probably run find if `/etc/X11/Xsession` exist, if so, you can simply add `autocutsel -fork` and restart your vnc session. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It can be sketchy, but has successfully worked for me in a pinch. Use Microsoft PowerToys Text Extractor. I can vouch for a ~47 character token with only one obvious 0 to O error at the very end of the string.

[Screenshot of tool description and hotkeys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMJNH.png)